# React-native app header overlaps with the phone header

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am using react-navigation to add custom header to my app. I am facing the same issue that is shown in the left image where the phone header overlaps with app's header. I tried to add SafeAreaView around my screen. But, it didn't make solve the problem.

[image]

Comment: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/handling-safe-area/ read full doc

Comment: If this is an expo app use https://reactnative.dev/docs/statusbar and make it translucent as false.

Answer (score 0):

it has two solutions. you can use

```
import React from 'react'
import {View,SafeAreaView, Text} from 'react-native'

const ConvertingFileScreen = () => {
    return(
        <SafeAreaView>
            <Text>ConvertingFileScreen</Text>
        </SafeAreaView>
    )
}

export default ConvertingFileScreen;
```

or simply with giving a marginTop of StatusBar.height like this.

```
import React from 'react'
import {View,SafeAreaView,StatusBar, Text,} from 'react-native'

const ConvertingFileScreen = () => {
    return(
        <View style={{marginTop:StatusBar.currentHeight}}>
            <Text>ConvertingFileScreen</Text>
        </View>
    )
}

export default ConvertingFileScreen;
```

Comment: Margin top is not a proper solution it is hard coding instead we should rely on libraries like Rn safe area context because they have support for many devices & add padding properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SafeAreaView or you can add some top spaces using useSafeAreaInsets from 'react-native-safe-area-context' It will solve the issue.

```
import React from 'react';
import { View,Text } from 'react-native';
import {useSafeAreaInsets} from 'react-native-safe-area-context';

const ConvertingFileScreen = () => {
 const { top } = useSafeAreaInsets();
 return (
   <View style={{marginTop: top}}>
     <Text>HI React Native</Text>
   </View>
 )
}
```

[Check for more details](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-safe-area-context)